# Path Issue in Matlab 2014b MCR Deployments with Added Folders

Tags: matlab, path, compilation

The compile command `mcc -m app.m -a file.ext -a ./dir` creates a directory `/app` containing `app.m` and `file.ext` and a directory `/dir` on the same level as `/app` containing all the files in `/dir`. What is the solution to add `/dir` in the `/app` directory, not on the same directory level (i.e. `/app/dir`)?

(Here is why I want to do this: In directory `/dir` are stored the images that are used by `app.m`, such as splash screen, button icons, default images, etc. `app.m` is accessing them using `imread('./dir/img.jpg')`. Since the compiler is adding the `/dir` directory one level below where it appears in the Matlab structure at development time, the images are no longer accessible when the standalone software is deployed. Hence I need to use a `isdeployed` switch to specify the correct path to the images for the development and deployment cases. I would rather avoid this, probably on code aesthetic grounds of an inconsistency of treating added files differently according to whether they are or not on the same directory level as the compiled application [file `file.ext` is put in `/app` while the image files from `/dir` are moved on the same level as `/app`].)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the path with the compile command, you may be able to use `mkdir` at run time.

Your command would look like this:

`status=mkdir('dir');`

The advantage to this is that the dir path is now below your app path, i.e. `/app/dir`.

The disadvantage is that the user of your program will need the privileges to create that directory.

If you need to compile the directory with the app, you could still use `mkdir` and then `movefile` to move all of your files to the new directory from the packaged one.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use two paths depending on whether the application is deployed or not. Code example:

```
% path to images directory 'pix'
apppath = mfilename('fullpath');
idx = strfind(apppath,filesep);
if isdeployed
    pixdir = [apppath(1:idx(end-1)),'pix',filesep];
else
    pixdir = [apppath(1:idx(end)),'pix',filesep];
end

% read image
img = imread(fullfile(pixdir,'logo.jpg'));
```